# Как удалить height у img

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

```
<img width="230" height="300" src="https://aaa.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
```

При выводе миниатюры WordPress добавляет ему width="230" height="300" по размеру картинки, но они мне очень мешают (ставлю сетку масонри). Как можно их удалить, чтобы img не превращалось в точку 0х0?

Или что сделать с WordPress, чтобы он не выводил width и height?

Дополнение

```
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        echo "<a class=\"wp-block-image\" href='";
        echo the_permalink();
        echo "'>";
        echo the_post_thumbnail();
        echo "</a>";
    };
    ?>
```

js

```
var $grid = $('.cat').masonry({
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
   $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

css

```
.wp-block-image {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
    width: calc(33.3% - 20px);
}
```

Comment: При правильной вёрстке эти width и height не мешают. Я выводил сетку masonry с width, height и srcset, и всё работает отлично. В чём ваша проблема? Покажите код php и результирующий html/css.

Comment: добавил код вывода

Comment: Код понятен. Что у вас конкретно не получается?

Comment: Проблема решилась, дело было в том что если у img нет заданного height и ему присвоить height: 100% то оно почему то получает значение - height:3.72827e+07px.
А если задано то получается нормально. Данное задание я делал после другого, в котором img не задавалось height и не стал присваивать height: 100% так как думал что это все испортит, а наоборот помогло.